# Firebase ionic 3 chat hora del mensaje enviado

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic, ionic3

Quiero mostrar la hora de cual envie el mensaje en el chat de ionic, esta es la forma que la estaba haciendo para enviar a la base de datos, pero como la transformo para mostrarla como hora y dia..

```
sendMessage(){
    this.time = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;



    console.log(this.newtime);
    if(this.userName != ""){
      if(this.message !=""){
        var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref().child("mensaje");

      messagesRef.push({mensaje:this.message, nombre:this.userName,time:this.time});
      this.message = "";
      }else{
        this.presentAlert2();
      }
    }else{
      this.presentAlert();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es crear un timestamp: donde este me haga un Date.now();

```
messagesRef.push({mensaje:this.message, nombre:this.userName,timestamp:Date.now()});
```

de esta forma, ahora en el chat.html llamarlo de esta forma

```
<h5 class="chat-time">{{message.timestamp  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h5>
```